# Jquery UI - Chrome can't do effect without runing my CSS

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, google-chrome

```
$(".switch .fs").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().effect( "shake");
});
```

please see: http://jsfiddle.net/V59c5/4/

If you use Chrome and click the button, you will see the switch messes up and leave a 4px gap, but Firefox does good.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @ArunPJohny first, doesn't work. second, won't make this a checkbox :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome adds a margin to checkboxes, you'll have to set the margin to zero

```
.switch input[type=checkbox] {
    margin: 0;

    ....
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/V59c5/5/)

Comment: wow! how fast are you! thanks a lot :D, and waiting to accept your answer 8 mins later!